# Why are we even assuming $\alpha Gb^2$+$\alpha Gb^2$ on one case and again $\alpha G(2b)^2$ on the other case?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, material-science, stress-strain

My point of interest is to know where the energy of two edge dislocation system comes from ($\alpha Gb^2$+$\alpha Gb^2$).It not really the formula that I am looking for but essentially why are we adding them and why is the Burger's Vector $b$ and not a scalar multiple of the same. why does the Burgers vector change from $b$ to $2b$ when the dislocations are extremely close.Please give the intutition to calculate how to calculated the total energy in the two process(when dislocations of like nature are very far and lying on the same slip plane  and (b) when dislocations are very close).NOTE:$\alpha$ is an empirical constant $G$ is shear modulus and $b$ is Burgers vector.

Comment: One edge dislocation has an energy of the form $\alpha G b^{2}$. A second edge dislocation a meter away in the crystal has the same energy - they are far enough apart not to have significant interaction. Now slide one right next to the other, to make and edge dislocation with a total Burgers vector of $2b$.

Comment: @JonCuster Although I did not ask can u tell me why are we getting $\alpha Gb^2$ as a formula for calculating the energy of dislocations?

Comment: https://www.tf.uni-kiel.de/matwis/amat/def_en/kap_5/backbone/r5_2_3.html

Comment: @JonCuster Thanks for explaining.While you wrote," Now slide one right next to the other, to make and edge dislocation with a total Burgers vector of 2b".Tell me something in such cases why should I be eligible for sliding and then call it a equivalent Burgers' vector?Should it not require a shear stress.Ideally things should be equal without providing any external stress.However I understood what you meant in your comment with regard to $\alpha Gb^2$